# ORACLE SQL: Reseting a counting sequence when ID ends for the next one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, reset

I am currently trying to reset a sequence if an ID of a Customer ends
right now, it is something like this:

```
CustomerID   Product PosNr
1            Banana   1
1            Papaya   2
1            Apple    3
2            Laptop   1
2            Keyboard 2
```

I hope it is clear what I mean.
The PosNr should reset for another Customer.

Can I Set up something like this while inserting the values into the table, or in any other way?

Comment: Is this for a result set -- the result of a query, for reporting -- or is it to be stored as an actual column value in a persistent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `row_number` analytic function with appropriate partitioning.

```
SQL> with test (customerid, product) as
  2    (select 1, 'banana'   from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'papaya'   from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'apple'    from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'laptop'   from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'keyboard' from dual
  7    )
  8  select customerid, product,
  9    row_number() over (partition by customerid order by product) posnr
 10  from test
 11  /

CUSTOMERID PRODUCT       POSNR
---------- -------- ----------
         1 apple             1
         1 banana            2
         1 papaya            3
         2 keyboard          1
         2 laptop            2

SQL>
```